# Performing many multiplications by the same large sparse matrix in C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have an iterative algorithm that requires multiplying a vector by a huge sparse matrix A at each iteration. The matrix A takes up several gigabytes of memory, is given in advance, and **never changes**. (If it helps, you could pretend that my algorithm is the conjugate gradient method for solving Ax  = b.)

Because the matrix A never changes, I think there must be some trick that will allow me to perform the multiplication very efficiently. For example, can I hard code A into my code so that the compiler knows the exact sparsity pattern and values of A as it performs the compilation? I would think that the compiler would be able to do a much better job if it knows the sparsity pattern of A.

What tricks can be used in this situation to multiply vectors by A very fast?

I'm currently using the Eigen3 matrix library, by the way.

Comment: Cache non-zero index into an array?

Comment: @javaLover Can you elaborate on that a bit? What exactly do you mean by "cache" here?

Comment: "A" is sparse = a lot of zero. Multiplication Ax need only to concern non-zero element of "A".   If the list of non-zero index is cache in advance, we can multiple only those in the list with some element in "x" to get the result of "Ax".   .... not sure ....Try to draft a real sparse matrix "A" with paper & pencil might give you some idea.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I am already using a sparse matrix-vector multiplication algorithm (it's part of the eigen3 library) which only works with the nonzero entries of A. I think this is what you were suggesting.

Comment: Just how big is this matrix if it's "sparse" and several gigabytes? 100000x100000?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Yes, it's sparse and several gigabytes. It has 47166 rows, 113954 columns, and about 7 percent of its entries are nonzero. This is for a radiation treatment planning algorithm, if you're curious.

Comment: You probably have to code whole Matrix yourself (from scratch).  I don't think Eigen3 is designed for such huge matrix.  Last time I tested, Eigen3 is fast, but not *marvelously* fast. ..... You may consider using GPU (glsl) rather than CPU, but I am not sure it is a viable solution for you.  GPU is really fast for parallel calculation but have a lot of limitation.

Comment: @javaLover Thanks. GPU implementation is on my list of things to try. Because A is a sparse matrix, I'm not sure the speedup from the GPU will be as dramatic as it would be for dense matrix-vector multiplication. I wonder if I'd be better off doing a parallel implementation using many cores but no GPU. I also wonder if some other architecture like a Xeon Phi or an FPGA or something would help more than a GPU in this situation. By the way, Eigen3 seems to tie with MATLAB for computing A*x (where x is a column vector) in this situation.

Comment: @littleO If the problem is memory bandwidth, which is quite possibly the case, a GPU has far greater bandwidth to its global and shared memory than does the CPU. Split the vector across the SMXes' `__shared__` memory and just watch that thing fly.

Comment: Whoosh!  You have done a well research!  My tip is that you should tell the GPU about the (dynamic) size of array + try to cap maximum amount of non-zero element.  It can speed up thing a bit.  ....  I think this is the most I can help, because I don't possess knowledge much more than that. Cheer.

Comment: @javaLover Thanks. I threw those terms out there, but I actually know very little about these computing hardware issues.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist That sounds interesting. What's an SMX? Can you link me to anything that would give me more details about how to try what you've suggested?

Comment: @littleO A Nvidia GPU has a small bunch (usually 4-60) of Streaming Multiprocessors (SMXes) that each have a few kilobytes of shared memory and a whole bunch of ALUs (typically 64-192). If you transcoded your matrix so that it is suitable for fast parsing by GPUs and split the vector so that each of the SMXs works on e.g. 2K or 4K elements of the vector and the corresponding 2K or 4K columns of the matrix, maybe you could see a speedup. But this would require arranging the sparse elements of the matrix so that each SMX can conveniently fetch the next block of work to do.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist That's interesting, thanks.

Comment: @littleO Not sure if you're still interested in this, but you should check out the ViennaCL library. It's a GPU-accelerated header-only linear algebra library. If you want a CPU-only tip, make sure that your matrix is stored in a row-major order. It tends to be a little bit faster than column-major. Lastly, if there is special structure to your matrix (beyond just sparsity) you can try to exploit that. Knowing something about the structure can reduce the memory traffic of loading the sparsity pattern, but it may require you to write your own matrix-vector multiply.